# read -p inside the function in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to write the function including `read -p`, however, for some reason the `read -p` always show first before other command, although other commands are before `read -p`. Here is my code:

```sh
function try {
    temp=10
    echo "$temp"
    while [[ $temp -gt 0 ]]
    do
        read -p  "what num do you want?" num
        echo "$num"
        temp=$((temp -  num))
        echo $temp
    done
}
run=`try`
echo "$run"
```

As the above code, I expected to see value of temp before statement "`what num do you want?`". However, here what I got:

```
what num do you want?5
what num do you want?5
10
5
5
5
0
```

Can anyone help me to solve my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you expect out of ``run=`try` `` here? This would capture stdout so none of the echo statements would show up on screen while it's running.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of the code in your question so it's easier to read?

Comment: @thatotherguy: I see what you meant. Can you tell me how can I fix my problem?

Comment: What should $run contain at the end?

Comment: @Cyrus: run contain is:10
5
5
5
0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate each line in your function which contains `echo` and append `>&2` to the new lines to redirect stdout to stderr.